# how to make ansible work on remote servers which has python 2.4

Tags: ansible

Making my question more meaningful...

Ansible controller server :
ansible 2.4.2.0
Python 2.7.5

Managed nodename (goldville):
Python 2.4.2

When i run #ansible goldville -m ping
I get the below error

File "/tmp/ansible_RSjze6/ansible_module_ping.py", line 8\r\n    from **future** import absolute_import, division, print_function\r\nSyntaxError: future feature absolute_import is not defined\r\n"

How can i use this node with python 2.4.2 to run playbooks from controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use python 2.4 some hosts or groups, set the `ansible_python_interpreter` inventory variable, try something like this:

```yaml
  [py24-hosts]
  goldville-py3 ansible_host=goldville 

  [py24-hosts:vars]
  ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin64/python2.4
```

But if you want use python2.4 for all you must set `interpreter_python` key in the `defaults` section in the configuraion file `ansible.cfg`

Docuementation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Comment: Suppose my SLES servername is goldville.. is the the below inventory correct.

[py24-hosts]
goldville-py3 ansible_host=goldville ansible_connection=local

[py23-hosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python24

Comment: Delete `ansible_connection` and validate that python is in /usr/bin/python24

Comment: its in   /usr/lib64/python2.4

Comment: [py24-hosts]
goldville-py3 ansible_host=goldville

[py23-hosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin64/python2.4

Comment: i posted my comment as reply above .. please check

Comment: I modified my answer, try it.

Comment: <ansiblecontroller:~/ansible> ansible py24-hosts  -u root  -m ping
goldville-py3 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to goldville closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin64/python2.4: No such file or directory\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}

Answer (score 0):

[py24-hosts]
goldville-py3 ansible_host=goldville

[py23-hosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin64/python2.4

When i run below it gave error
#ansible goldville -m ping

Failed to parse /home/ansible/ansiblehosts with ini plugin: /home/ansible/ansiblehosts:4: Section [py23-hosts:vars] not valid
for undefined group: py23-hosts

Comment: Edited my question more meaningful. Please help.